# Netlify site works in Chrome but not in Firefox, Opera, Edge

Tags: reactjs, hosting, web-hosting, netlify

For example this site opens on all browsers, this is simply a brand new create react project

https://pricecomparesite.netlify.com/

However these older projects only open in Chrome

https://robo-cards-with-search.netlify.com/

https://ecommercestorewithfirebase.netlify.com/

Strangely enough this one works

https://ordercustomburger.netlify.com/

This is the first day i am using Netlify, and of course my projects are working locally, i tried uploading both with the Netlify site and CLI, and i ran "npm i" & "npm run build" before upload. The robo-cards-with-search site was broken but following the advice of deleting node folder and changing react script version to 3.4 fixed it.

I suppose i uploaded the site correctly, else it wouldn't work on chrome and i followed all guidance i could find, but even google doesn't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are having a redux devtools extension issue.

Read about the usage [here](https://extension.remotedev.io/#usage) on how to handle other browsers.

Currently you are using:

```js
// Combine Middleware and Chrome Dev tools. Else it doesn't work
const middleWare = compose(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
```

Without being able to debug, it is hard to know where this might be failing on a browser that doesn't support the redux devtools.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. I was too focused on netlify.